# Div is not centered properly, why?

Tags: html, css

explainmehow.com

The white boxes in the middle of the screen, which have text in them, are not centered. You can see it extra clear, if you make your screen really small.

White box:

```
.step {
  background-color: white;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #303030;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: please post your (relevant) mark up here.

Comment: removing float left makes it even worse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `width: 100%;` to `width: 90%;` so you aren't extending the page by adding `margin-right/left:5%` and set `padding:15px;` to `padding: 15px 0;` so only top and bottom gets padding:

```
#contentholder {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
    width: 90%;
}
```

Then:

Get rid of `float:left` on the class `.step`.  Boom it is all centered.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The CSS of the main content `div` is this:

```
 #contentholder {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Take a look at the box model. The width, padding, and margin together make it so that the total width of the element is larger than the width of the screen. The white boxes inside that element are centered properly though.

So, the problem isn't the white boxes, the problem is the parent element.